# Passing Object to Java from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

i'm in trouble with this problem.
I've a Javascript structur like this:

```
$scope.setting= {
    enabled: false,
    host:"",
    port:"",
    user:"",
    pwd:"",
    path:"/",
    filePrefix:"",
    type:"",
    sendInterval:"",
    dataPeriod:"",
    compression:false,
    subscription:[]
};
```

In the controller i modify the subscription array, but when i pass it to the java code:

```
$http.post('/api/testAndSetFTPSetting', $scope.setting)
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    });
```

the subscription array is null.

Here the API

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/testAndSetFTPSetting"}, method={RequestMethod.POST})
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean testAndSetFTPSetting(FTPConfiguration ftp) throws JAXBException {

        System.out.println(ftp.getSubscribtion().size()); // here i've ever 0 and ftp.getSubscribtion() return me null

        return true;

    }
```

Here the Java Class who controls the object:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="FTPconfiguration")
    @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class FTPConfiguration{
        boolean enabled = false;            
        String host="127.0.0.1";            
        int port=22;                        
        String user="root";                 
        String pwd="";                      
        String path="/";                    
        String filePrefix="data";           
        FTPType type=FTPType.SFTP;          
        int sendInterval=15;                
        int dataPeriod=5;                   
        boolean compression=false;          
        @XmlElementWrapper(name="subscriptions")
        List<String> subscription = new LinkedList<String>();   


        public FTPConfiguration() {
        }

        public FTPConfiguration(boolean enabled,String host, int port, String user, String pwd, String path, String filePrefix,
                FTPType type, int sendInterval, int dataPeriod, boolean compression, List<String> subscription) {
            super();
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.user = user;
            this.pwd = pwd;
            this.path = path;
            this.filePrefix = filePrefix;
            this.type = type;
            this.sendInterval = sendInterval;
            this.dataPeriod = dataPeriod;
            this.compression = compression;
            if(subscription != null)
                this.subscription.addAll(subscription);
        }
        // setter and getter method
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: Try to change subscription from List to array: String[] subscription

Comment: i prefer to don't change this because FTPConfiguration is used in a lots of other classes.

Comment: should it be `subscriptions:[]` (with an `s`) in your javascript?

Comment: In Json property its 'subscription', and in Java the @XMLElemmentWrapper's name is 'subscriptions'. Is that right?

Comment: Yes because the XML is <subscriptions> <subscription>1</subscription> <subscription>2</subscription> ...  </subscriptions>

Comment: What about the @RequestBody in the parameter? Like : public boolean testAndSetFTPSetting(@RequestBody FTPConfiguration ftp) throws JAXBException

Comment: Return this error --> 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: @Mr Spoon if i pass an FTPConfiguration Object to AngularJS the structure is subscription without s.

Comment: Angular default content type to post is JSON, Did you changed it?

Comment: No, JSON still the default

Comment: @ilGiudice, try to send another property, like user='test' in your js. Then say to us if this value was parsed correct in java.

Comment: @BrunoMD yes, all the other properties of the javascript object are passed correctly. if i change 'host', 'pwd', 'user' etc etc are corrects when passed to the Java. Only the Array is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved!!! The problem was that the javascript array in java is a comma separated String. For this the value that i received was null!

```
EX 
JavaScript OBJ
var arr = ["1", "2", "3"];
$http.post('someUrl', arr)...

Java
@RequestMapping(value = {"/someUrl"}, method={RequestMethod.POST})
public void foo(String s) { // s will be = "1,2,3"

}
```